# Does CiviCRM OG Sync support PHP 7 +?

Tags: groups, modules

After updating PHP to 7.1 we are now unable to save new organic groups and receive a Civi error. No new group is created in CiviCRM.

```
backTrace
#0 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(377): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Bridge/OG/Utils.php(145): CRM_Core_Error::fatal()
#2 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Bridge/OG/Drupal.php(228): CRM_Bridge_OG_Utils::groupID("OG Sync Group :12822:", NULL, TRUE)
#3 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/modules/civicrm_og_sync/civicrm_og_sync.module(241): CRM_Bridge_OG_Drupal::og((Array:4), "add")
#4 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/modules/civicrm_og_sync/civicrm_og_sync.module(68): _civicrm_og_sync_node_action(Object(stdClass))
#5 /includes/module.inc(965): civicrm_og_sync_node_update(Object(stdClass))
#6 /modules/node/node.module(1180): module_invoke_all("node_update", Object(stdClass))
#7 /modules/node/node.pages.inc(459): node_save(Object(stdClass))
#8 /includes/form.inc(1524): node_form_submit((Array:65), (Array:23))
#9 /includes/form.inc(906): form_execute_handlers("submit", (Array:65), (Array:23))
#10 /includes/form.inc(386): drupal_process_form("course_node_form", (Array:65), (Array:23))
#11 /includes/form.inc(131): drupal_build_form("course_node_form", (Array:23))
#12 /modules/node/node.pages.inc(14): drupal_get_formcourse_node_form", Object(stdClass))
#13 /includes/menu.inc(527): node_page_edit(Object(stdClass))
#14 /index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We solved our issue - it appears to be related to a separate bug. The OG name we created had some formatting that either OG or the extension (or Civi) did not like

"Course Name 19-20: More things about the course: Subtext"

We changed it to "Course Name 19-20" and then it saved the groups, etc. and worked properly in PHP 7.1